# vertx-db2-client return error codes when querying data with chinese characters

Tags: db2, vert.x

[image]

Like picture above

Are there some options to control the encoding? (switch between UTF8 and GBK?)

I found a `DEFAULT_CHARSET` property(the value is `utf8`) in `io.vertx.db2client.DB2ConnectOptions`, but no code use it.
Is there a way to pass custom charset to DB2ConnectOptions instance?

I tried to set `charset` directly in config file(the `connect` part will be parsed into a SqlConnectOptions instance), but it seems the client still use utf8

```
  connect:
    host: 192.168.0.100
    port: 50000
    database: test
    charset: GBK
    pipelined: true
    user: test
    password: test
  pool:
    name: test
    shared: true
```

result of `select  name,value from sysibmadm.dbcfg where name in ('codepage','codeset','territory','country')`:

```json
[
{
"NAME": "codepage",
"VALUE": "1386"
},
{
"NAME": "codeset",
"VALUE": "GBK"
},
{
"NAME": "country",
"VALUE": "86"
},
{
"NAME": "territory",
"VALUE": "CN"
}
]
```

Comment: Not enough details. Please edit your question to add facts. What is the Db2-server platform (Z/OS, i series,  Linux/Unix/Windows/Cloud)?  What is the jdbc driver version being used by verx?  What is the codepage of the database, or the table?  Are you using console output or a GUI? If using a console, what is the active codepage in that console or terminal window?

Comment: it's vertx driver, not jdbc. vertx driver do not have different versions on different platform

Comment: From your edits to the question, it appears that Db2-LUW is being used. How did you verify the codepage of the Db2 database? On your vertx client, are you running at a console or in some GUI? If using a console, which operating system, which locale/codepage is in use by that console?

Comment: The db2 is running on a windows server, and it uses the system default charset GBK. If a use a jdbc driver(luw), it can auto detect the charset and return correct string, but it seems vertx-db2-client always use utf8. I'm searching for a way to config the client to use GBK

Comment: Db2-LUW on Microsoft-Windows supports codepage 1386, codeset GBK, territory-code 86,  and also codepage 1250 (codeset 1250) with territory-code 385 (among many others). We cannot tell unambiguously from your question or comments which __exact__ codepage/territory-code/code-set is in use by the database. Precision matters.

Comment: I checked the server response and it's GBK. I run `select HEX(t.a) as col` to get the hex value and decode it with GBK and the result is correct

Comment: Please edit your question to show the plain text output of this SQL query `select  name,value from sysibmadm.dbcfg where name in ('codepage','codeset','territory','country')` , or if you lack permission then ask the DBA to do it.

Comment: have put the result above